# Twitter application authentication to get user timelines for single user account

Tags: scribe

Does Scribe provide a way to incorporate Application authentication for Twitter ?

The details of this authentication are as described here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth

We need to get the user_timeline for an application twitter account and do not want to go through the user OAuth 1.0a authentication process since the user is the same.

Thanks